# Can't resolve all parameters for a CustomComponent in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

When I try to build the project for production I get the following error:

> Can't resolve all parameters for EmployeeComponent in
>   C:/.../src/app/employee/employee.component.ts: (?, ?, ?).

Although when I serve the application I do not get any errors and the app works fine.

The `EmployeeComponent` looks as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Score } from '../score/score';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string;
  employeeId: number;
  totalScore: number;
  scores: Score[] = new Array<Score>();

  public constructor(name: string, employeeId: number, scores: number[]) {
    this.name = name;
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
    this.totalScore = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      this.scores[i] = new Score(scores[i], i);
      this.totalScore += scores[i];
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setTotalScore() {
    this.totalScore = 0;
    for(let score of this.scores) {
      this.totalScore += Number(score.value);
    }
  }

}
```

The `EmployeeComponent` has a `scores` variable which is of Type `Score` and is defined as follows:

```
export class Score {
   value: number;
   id: number;
   constructor(value: number, id: number) {
       this.value = value;
       this.id = id;
    }
 }
```

I am creating the employees as follows:

```
import { EmployeeComponent } from './employee/employee.component';

export var mockEmployees: EmployeeComponent[] = [
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 1", 1, [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 2", 2, [11, 21, 31, 41, 51]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 3", 3, [12, 22, 32, 42, 52]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 4", 4, [13, 23, 33, 43, 53]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 5", 5, [14, 24, 34, 44, 54]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 6", 6, [15, 25, 35, 45, 55]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 7", 7, [16, 26, 36, 46, 56]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 8", 8, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 9", 9, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 10", 10, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 11", 11, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 12", 12, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 13", 13, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 14", 14, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 15", 15, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 16", 16, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 17", 17, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 18", 18, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 19", 19, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 20", 20, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 21", 21, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 22", 22, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 23", 23, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 24", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 25", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 26", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 27", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 28", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 29", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 30", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 31", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 32", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 33", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 34", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 35", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 36", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 37", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 38", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 39", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 40", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 41", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 42", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 43", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 44", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 45", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 46", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 47", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 48", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 49", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 50", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 51", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 52", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 53", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 54", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 55", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 56", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 57", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 58", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 59", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 60", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 61", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 63", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 64", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 65", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 66", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 67", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 68", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 69", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 70", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 71", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 72", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 73", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 74", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 75", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 76", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 77", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 78", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 79", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 80", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 81", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 82", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 83", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 84", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 85", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 86", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 87", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 88", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 89", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
    new EmployeeComponent("Lorem Ipsum 90", 24, [17, 27, 37, 47, 57]),
];
```

Could anyone tell me why am I getting this error?

Comment: Can you run `ng serve --aot`? What errors do you get?

Comment: Try serving again with `--aot` enabled and see whether that works or not. DI is probably trying to resolve things beforehand and it fails.

Comment: I would try to make all those ctor parameters optional.

Comment: How do you use the `EmployeeComponent`? You should probably use `@Input` instead of the constructor.

Comment: A component can not has this arguments in the constructor. (only acept parameters to make a DI)

Comment: where are you providing name, employeeId and scores?

Comment: When I run ng serve --aot, I get the same error: ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for EmployeeComponent in C:/.../src/app/employee/employee.component.ts: (?, ?, ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `EmployeeComponent` is an angular `Component` (it has `@component` annotation) you can't give inputs in the constructor as you have done. 
Please check [this link](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) for clarity.
Also you can't create components with `new`

Please use `@Input` s to give those inputs. Check [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the problem. I created an Employee class, then in EmployeeComponent created a variable and initialized it with the mockEmployees. The mockEmployees had a variable of array of Employee.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Input` to populate your component with data:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  name: string;
  @Input()
  employeeId: number;
  @Input()
  scoreNumbers: number[]
  totalScore: number;
  scores: Score[] = new Array<Score>();

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.totalScore = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      this.scores[i] = new Score(this.scoreNumbers[i], i);
      this.totalScore += scores[i];
    }
  }
```

Then use the component in a template with

```
<app-employee [name]="myName" [employeeId]="myEmployeeId" [scoreNumbers]="myScores"></app-employee>
```

where `myName`, `myEmployeeId` and `myScores` are variables with the data you want to display.

Read more about the data flow in Angular components in [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#input-and-output-properties).